# How to set page title in blazor?

Tags: blazor

As Blazor being a SPA framework, I would like to know is it possible to set a page title for each individual page in Blazor?

I am currently working on Blazor webassembly project and cannot figure out a way how to add a page title since there is only one index.html as it should be in SPA, but would be really useful if it can be achieved to set title for each  "page".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Note: starting with .Net 6.0 there is official support for changing the title, so the solution below is no longer needed.**

1. Provide following script in your index.html (or in an included .js file):

   ```
   <script>
        setTitle = (title) => { document.title = title; };
   </script>
   ```

2. In each page inject the jsinterop:

   ```
   @inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime;
   ```
3. After each render, set the document title to the value of your choice:

   ```
   @code
   {
      protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
      {
         await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setTitle", "this is the new title"); ;        
      }    
   }
   ```

Comment: The IDE may complain about not being able to find `IJSRuntime`. Try to build and run anyways, it's just a IDE glitch.

Comment: The InvokeVoidAsync should be called only once, when the value of firstRender is true.  The code above is executed each time the OnAfterRenderAsync occurs.

Comment: @enet: That is correct, but the above code is from a use case where the main body of my page consists of different components that are swapped in and where I want the page title to reflect the component that is actually shown. By executing this code on each 'OnAfterRenderAsync' I ensure the title is updated whenever the main component has changed.

Comment: How can we make it SEO friendly? Crawlers will see the page title BEFORE javascript chnages

Comment: Newbie here, I cannot find an index.html in Blazor. Do I need to create? If yes, where do I create the file?

Comment: @CBBSpike: This example was written for a preview version of Blazor (serverside). You can add the script to _Host.cshtml instead (e.g. right after the blazor.js script).

Comment: This is the best way based on my experience. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68271272/145122

Comment: .NET 6 shipped official support for this scenario for both server and client-side Blazor. I'd recommend using the official APIs for this which are described in some of the more recent/updated answers.

Answer (score 28):

From `ASP.NET CORE 6.0`, the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/control-head-content?view=aspnetcore-6.0) says that we can **Influence HTML `<title>` tag elements easily** by using `PageTitle` component.

Add the `HeadOutlet` Component in `Program.cs`

```cs
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
```

Then use `PageTitle` Component

```
<PageTitle>@title</PageTitle>
```

<s>**Update 1:**</s>

<s>Looks like this API has been put on hold to improve further. This has been removed from official docs link. Here is the [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25705) tracking the same. I'll update the answer once the API finally gets available in docs.</s>

**Update 2:**

The above issue has been resolved and `ASP.NET Core` team added `<PageTitle>` component in `ASP.NET Core 6.0`. I have also updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Title didn't worked here, but title yes (lowercase)

Comment: This is not implemented currently in blazor. As mentioned in the answer, please track the github issue for official release if `<Title>` component in blazor

Comment: `builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");` in the `program.cs` file is no longer needed. You can Just use the `<PageTitle>` element now.

Comment: @TysonGibby though the same as well but it didn't work until I added the `Program.cs` part

Comment: @ZiadAkiki the documentation has been updated to show that you now add the outlet component in the _Layout.cshtml file *for prerendered projects*. It implies (fuzzy) that you still need to add it to program.cs for other wasm projects.

Comment: @TysonGibby Adding the `HeadOutlet` in `program.cs` is still needed for net-7.0 Blazor WebAssembly

Answer (score 18):

In ASP.NET CORE 5.0, a new component for **Title** is added

```
 <Title value="Page title" />
```

Msdn Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0#influence-html-head-tag-elements

First add the using statement in the component

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Extensions.Head
```

You can install (if not installed) using the command.

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Extensions --version 5.0.0-preview9.20467.1
```

5.0.0-preview9.20467.1 is the version when I am writing this. Please check the nuget url for the latest version

Nuget url: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Extensions/

Then add the Title tag.

```
<Title Value="My page title" />
```

See the sample output image below

[image]

Comment: Don't you just love Microsoft documentation.
Every time I follow a link on the web to a Microsoft document the content seems to not be the same as when the link was createrd.

Comment: I also needed to add the following script to my index.html to make this work:  <script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Extensions/headManager.js"></script>

Answer (score 9):

.NET 6 RC1 introduced the `PageTitle` component to handle this scenario.
The `PageTitle` component is inside of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web` namespace.

You can place the component anywhere within your Blazor app and the contents of the `PageTitle` will be reflected as the title of your page. If you have multiple `PageTitle` components, the one that has been rendered last will become the title of your page.

In this case, the title will be "Page Title 2":

```html
@page "/counter"

<PageTitle>Page Title 1</PageTitle>
<PageTitle>Page Title 2</PageTitle>
```

For `PageTitle` and `HeadContent` to work, you do need to add the `HeadOutlet` as a root component.
If you're using Blazor WASM completely client-side (no pre-render), you need to add the following line to your Startup.cs file after adding your `App` as a root component:

```cs
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
```

The `head::after` CSS selector instructs where to render the output of the HeadOutlet which will be respected for `HeadContent`, but if there's a title tag already present, the existing title tag will be updated.

If you're using Blazor WASM with pre-rendering, you'd put the following line inside the head of your _Layout.cshtml file:

```html
<component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" />
```

This is assuming you have a _Layout.cshtml file from following [Microsoft's docs to setup Blazor WASM pre-rendering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=webassembly).

If you want more details, I wrote [a blog post on PageTitle, HeadContent, and HeadOutlet with more details at the Telerik Blog](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/get-your-head-together-blazor-new-headcontent-pagetitle).

I also just found some very new [documentation from Microsoft on PageTitle, HeadContent, etc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/control-head-content?view=aspnetcore-6.0) that is relevant.

Answer (score 6):

For those targeting .NET Core 3.1

Kudos to this [post](https://exceptionnotfound.net/setting-the-page-title-in-a-blazor-app-net-core/), you can make a reusable component.

Add below script to a js file, or add to **index.html**

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
...
</head>

<body>
...
    <script>
        window.setTitle = (title) => {
            document.title = title;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

In the shared folder create a new component **PageTitle.razor**

[image: folder layout]

```cs
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime;

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await SetTitle();
    }

    private async Task SetTitle()
    {
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setTitle", Title);
    }
}
```

Add to the razor page you want to change the name of:

```cs
<PageTitle Title="Home sweet home" />
```

[image: Index.razor]

[image: Final result]

Comment: For "InvalidOperationException: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being statically rendererd. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method.", handle it inside "protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)" instead.

Answer (score 2):

For **Blazor Server** in **.net6.0**

Add the following snippet inside the `<head>`tag contained within the **_Host.cshtml** file:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
<component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

Example

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
<head>   
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
 <title>Title Placeholder</title>
 <base href="~/" />
 <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />        
</head>
```

Then within your various Razor components you can use the `<PageTitle>` tag.

ExampleComponent.razor

```
@page "/ExampleComponent"
<PageTitle>Supplier Documents</PageTitle>
```

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/prerendering-and-integration?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server#prerendering-configuration)

Comment: Thank you! Adding the `<component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />` was the missing piece for me in Blazor Server.

Answer (score 2):

Since .NET 6 you can just use:

```
<PageTitle>@YourTitle</PageTitle>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Majorsoft.Blazor.Components.Common.JsInterop/). It can change your Blazor **page Title** and even **icon** if you van to show notifications. Check the [documentation](https://github.com/majorimi/blazor-components/blob/master/.github/docs/JsInterop.md#html-head-js-see-demo-app) for more details.

[image]

Try it out in the [demo app](https://blazorextensions.z6.web.core.windows.net/jsinterop#head-js).

Answer (score 1):

The helper jsakamoto Toolbelt.Blazor.HeadElement is the only the solve the page title changes properly. In the end of the day, the main reason to change the title is to help SEO, therefore it must have SERVER SIDE PRERENDERING.

[image: Blazor Head Element Helper]

[image]

To use the helper, access the author's instructions on https://dev.to/j_sakamoto/yet-another-way-to-changing-the-page-title-in-blazor-and-more-43k

And more info on https://github.com/jsakamoto/Toolbelt.Blazor.HeadElement/#blazor-head-element-helper-

I would like to ask the author of this stackoverflow question, to make this the selected answer.

Comment: When you use Blazor is because you want to code in C#, not in JS so I believe this is the right answer as you can do the requested work without any JS at all, as that's all embedded in the Toolbelt.Blazor.HeadElement component.  Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

*Starting on Net6 Preview 7 ...*

You can [Modify HTML  content from Blazor components](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-7/#modify-html-head-content-from-blazor-components)

> Blazor now has built-in support for modifying HTML  element content from components, including setting the  and adding  elements.

Comment: Well, I noticed that if `index.html` has `title`, when the app is loaded for the first time, the title in `index.html` is displayed. Only on navigation, the `PageTitle` is rendered. How can we have `PageTitle` displayed in the first load (with index.html title still there)?

Comment: @Meer, this was a bug in previous previews and RC's which now has been fixed with release of .NET 6 RC2. This should now behave as expected. Here's the bug issue on GitHub for your reference: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/36967

Comment: Thanks for the info @Swimburger. Updated to lastest RC, don't see the issue now.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<PageTitle>Your Page Title</PageTitle>`

Answer (score -1):

I need an SEO-friendly solution and I found my own solution. Maybe you can use it and this solution is multilingual.

We need a helper static class:

```
public static class MetaHelper
{
    public class MetaModel
    {
        public MetaModel(string title, string description)
        {
            Title = title;
            Description = description;
        }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public static MetaModel GetMeta(string path)
    {
        var culture = CultureHelper.GetCultureSlug();
        // culture is ".com/en/faqs" or ".com/de/faqs" etc
        path = path.Replace($"{culture }/", "");

        if (path == "faqs")
        {
            return new MetaModel("Faq - website", "Frequently Asked Questions about ....");
        }
        else if (path == "page2")
        {}......


        return new MetaModel("Web site - Default Name", "Default description");
    }
}
```

and we can use this helper in _host.cshtml page

```
@{
Layout = null;

var meta = MetaHelper.GetMeta(Request.Path);
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>@meta.Title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="@meta.Description">
```