# Blazor WebAssembly Update Page Title

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, webassembly, blazor-client-side

**Framework**: .NET Core 3.1 (Blazor WebAssembly)

I have just scaffolded a simple Blazor WebAssembly app, and added multiple pages.
On redirection to the specific page, I want to update the window/tab title to `[Page Name] | My App`.

In ASP.NET MVC or Core, we could use the `ViewBag` to update the `<title>` element in `Layout.cshtml`.

What would be the equivalent approach in Blazor WebAssembly app?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set page title in blazor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58863542/how-to-set-page-title-in-blazor)

Comment: Is it possible to update the title without using the ```IJSRuntime```?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58863542/how-to-set-page-title-in-blazor/). There are a few answers I also [recommended to use this Nuget package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58863542/how-to-set-page-title-in-blazor/66589682#66589682).

Comment: If you're able to upgrade to the upcoming release of .NET 6, I would recommend doing so. The new release includes new bits to help you handle this scenario. I don't want to duplicate my answer, but here's a link to my answer at the other SO post asking the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69562788/2919731

Answer (score 3):

You should be using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Extensions nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Extensions. It is currently still in prerelease but stable.

It does **exactly** what you are looking for, you get components for `<Title>`, `<Link>`, and `<Meta>` tags. It still uses JavaScript to perform the update, but it is much cleaner than the other solutions out there. I personally use this package successfully in a production app. Here's how to get it setup:

1. Install the nuget package `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Extensions -Prerelease`
2. In your `index.html` file under `wwww` root folder, add a reference to the JS file:
   `<script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Extensions/headManager.js" type="module"></script>`
3. On any `*.razor` page you want to set the title on, or in the `_Imports.razor` file for a folder, add the using directive: `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.Extensions.Head`
4. Use the various tags as needed:

```html
<Title value="My Page Title" />
<Meta name="description" content="My Blazor Component" />
<Link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
<Link rel="alternate" href="/feed.rss" type="application/rss+xml" />
```

Comment: How could you use the link tag to get an icon on the title? Stuck trying to figure this one out.

Comment: @JeremyS. Are you trying to add an icon into the page title text? Or a favicon?

Answer (score 1):

Likewise, here is a different blog post on how to set the page title. Essentially, you use the navigation manager to inject the current page, and then use JS Interop to call out an update the the page title.

https://www.iambacon.co.uk/blog/setting-the-document-title-in-your-blazor-app

There are definitely a few ways to do this. If you have issues implementing, let me know!

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)